# Using strcmp to compare a char pointer and a literal

Tags: c, pointers, char, strcmp

I've been trying this for about an hour and looked at other places online but still was not able to accomplish what I'm trying to do. This should probably be something simple but I have not coded in C in quite awhile so I may be missing something. Anyway I want to use strcmp to compare something in a variable called char *args and a literal like "qw".

I am in main and pass a function this args variable and when I get it back I want to compare like this: Maybe I am just completely doing this in a dumb way.

```
char *args;
char **svdArray;

int keepTrack = 0;
int beforeTrack = 0;

svdArray = malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
while (1)
{           

if(!(strcmp(args[0], "r")) && (!strcmp(args[0], "rr")))
  {

    svdArray[keepTrack] = args[0];


     keepTrack++;
  }
```

All I want to happen is if I args[0] has something in it besides rr or r I want to execute the code inside the if statement. However as of now the flow just never enters it and I don't know why.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!!!

Comment: Your example program isn't even syntactically correct - please show your *actual* code.

Comment: `args[]` does not compile.

Comment: strcmp returns 0 (false) when the strings are equal, so the function can be used to sort different strings

Comment: The logical `or`-operator in C is `||`.

Comment: `args[0]` is a `char` and cannot be equal to `rr` by definition.

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote some of my code and eventually arrived at an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` compares both strings in whole.

To only test for parts use `strstr()` like for example so:

```
if (strstr(args, "r")) || strstr(args, "rr")))
{
  svdArray[keepTrack] = args;
  keepTrack++;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `args` a `char*`?  so `args[0] would be a `char`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was somehow fixated on the `args` passed into `main()`, which are indeed `char ** args`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `char*` to `strcmp`, like `args`.

Here is the prototype for `strcmp` from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

`int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );`

So since `args` is a `char*` and `"r"` will give you a `char*` you should try:

```
/* since you're learning, print out what this thing does */
#include <stdio.h>
printf("Output: %d\n",strcmp(args,"r"));
```